# Isn't it inefficient to have intake vents on the bottom of laptops since even a hard flat surface blocks off the vents?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling

This is something about laptop design that I don't understand: Laptops typically put intake vents at the bottom and exhaust vents at the sides or back. Putting the intake vents at the bottom has always struck me as inefficient for cooling.

Since the vents are at the bottom, wouldn't the surface the laptop is on block off those intake vents? I understand that laptops usually have small "legs" or stands at the corners that slightly raise the laptop if it is on a flat, hard surface like a table, but they only do so by a millimeter or so at best, so that the space between laptop and table for air to flow in is still minimal.

It seems to me like it would make more sense to put *both* intake and exhaust vents at the sides or back.

Comment: How much air do you believe intake vents take in? Also, you realize that fans kick in as a preventative measure waaaay prior to them actually being needed to cool off. They don’t just kick in right at the moment the system is in critical shape; it’s a guestimate/gamble based on system tolerances and behavior.

Comment: I imagine that intake vents on the bottom are an artifact of fans being fairly thin and to long/wide to mount vertically.

Comment: Also, you may be missing that the thin underneath area is not a pipe, its a plane, and can suck in vastly more air then a pipe of that diameter.

Answer (score 2):

Read most manuals coming with most laptops and they'll say you ought to use them on a flat, hard surface, or your lap, both of which offer ample space for airflow to the average laptop computer.

They'll also say you should NOT under and circumstances use the laptop on a flat soft surface such as a bed or cushion as that will stop the vents.

Some laptops have undersized cooling arrangements that, even with careful use, are insufficient to deal with the system under load.

But most modern CPUs scale their load very effectively based on how the cooling solution is working.

Comment: while what you say is vaild I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: It attempted to address the actual question rather than simply the one that was presented. OP is concerned about cooling and so I gave them information about how to best accomplish that. Their other question is opinion based, and based on design aspects unique to each system, and as such cannot be authoritatively answered.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right that its opinion based. I am not an expert, but I'm pretty confident my comments are correct, and were it something I had read  rather then the result of a thought experiment  I'd post it as an answer. If I am correct its the result of logical deduction.

Comment: Agreed with comments above that this response doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

After repairing and servicing every make and model of laptop ever made (Lenovo, Dell, Apple, Samsung, Toshiba, etc. etc. etc.) for almost 30 years, the longest-operating and best-designed laptop I have come across was the Samsung ATIV Book 9.  It had no vents except along the hinge and a couple small intakes near the back on the bottom where it would not be blocked much (entire hinge.. a very large, robust hinge-vent...and when you opened it up, the dual-fan heatpipe design was impressive to behold, to say the least), and lasted ***9.5 years*** under heavy daily road-warrior use (sitting on lap on a woman's dress, on a blanket on bed in a hotel room, etc.).  It had an aircraft-grade super rigid aluminum body and i7 processor also. It still worked ****literally**** like brand new (fast and responsive) until the day it suddenly stopped booting due to old power-supply capacitors.

Oh, and the battery still charged to 93% of original capacity and never needed replacing after 9.5 years. An engineering marvel.

Vents on the bottom in actual real-word use will always get blocked (blankets, women do wear dresses still *gasp*, so "laptop" doesn't work well, table tops, dust and lint sucking in from the bottom, etc., etc.)

Why do they put large lint-sucking vents on the bottom still?  **Because they sell more laptops that way...and the fan design usually does need something perpendicular to the fan, for intake**  Honestly. Engineers are smart people in general, but no company wants their laptop lasting **TOO** long either, so that engineering goes into making it last the "right" amount of time. Just talking from 30 years' experience... so....

If a laptop just sits on a desk (not used as a mobile computer) and isn't moved much or power-cycled, then any vent design will probably work fine though, and it'll likely work a long time.  But that is not as typical a use-case in my experience. Most laptops I see last 3-5 years under more typical heavy use and travel, and die from heat-related issues and fan failure.

[image: Samsung ATIV Book 9]

Answer (score 0):

Laptop vents generally are at the bottom.  The intake fans are more than powerful enough to pull in air, even if the laptop is raised by a few millimeters by the feet.  You do not want laptop vents on top, as that would allow more dirt and debris to enter.  Typically the keyboard is the only opening on top and debris falls and stays in that.

I have seen laptops running for over a decade, without being turned off, and they work fine.

Laptops have been made this way for a *very, very* long time and if this was a bad idea, manufacturers wouldnt make design them this way.  If it was an issue, then then there would be lost profit due to returns from defective laptops.  Engineers *tend* to be very smart people.